# express 4 router with external file

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following files

```
lib/pub
lib/pub/index.js
app.js
```

On App.js

I have:

```
// app.js
var express = require("express")
, app = express()
, router = express.Router()
;
... 
router.use('/pub',require('./pub'));
```

and then on index.js

```
// pub/index.js
var express  = require('express')
, router = express.Router()
;
console.log("file loaded successfully")
module.exports = function(){
  router.get('/',function(req,res){
     console.log("got the get request")
  })
}
```

The problem I have when I do `localhost/pub` request, I never get the `got the get request`, no matter whatever I try to change the code around, trying to add `pub` to the path.

```
router.get('/',...
router.get('/pub',...
router.get('./pub,...
router.get('./',...
router.get('pub',...
etc...
```

None of those or any other silly way I have attempted work... I can never get the log to say yes I got the request...

What am I doing wrong ! (expressjs changes so frequently and radically, any web tutorials become redundant or any previous help others got)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(edited to reflect comments)

If you want to move your routes to an external file, use the following pattern:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

require('./routes')(app);
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/pub', function(req, res) {
    console.log('got the get!');
    res.end();
  });
};
```

Comment: No luck either ... I get the file loaded successfully... but how would index.js know it's a get or post etc...? with this method?

Comment: I'm still a little uncertain as to what you're trying to do.  What type of request to what url should trigger the log?

Comment: if I have request `localhost/pub` I expect `got the get request`, I am trying to avoid cluttering the app.js file with loads of routing on the same file as there will be loads of those.

Comment: yes, that did it, although the `./routes` had to be a string I am sure it was a typo.

Comment: @Val thanks for catching that.  Would you mind upvoting/accepting?

Comment: But... how if i want to use connection to querying database in this external router?